# R function with text input

Tags: r, function, text

I have a function in R that takes as input a matrix and outputs a data frame with:

```
name   X    Y      Z
  Amy   25     40   78
  Brad    67    78   90
   ..
```

I would like to add a parameter to the function that is text, like this:

```
  f(x,NameChoice) { #...matrix calcs #
                return( subset( dataframe, Name = NameChoice ) )
}
```

so that `f(x,Amy)` would have output:

```
Amy   25     40   78
```

Comment: Make it `f(x,"Amy")` and it should work fine - the `Name` column actually contains the string `"Amy"`, so that should be the argument that is passed to the function.

Comment: You have the column as `name` in the matrix, but `Name` in `subset`. Also, you need `==` to test equality, not `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code with out `suspect` method.

```
name val1 val2 val3 val4
abc    1    5    9   13
def    2    6   10   14
ghi    3    7   11   15
klm    4    8   12   16

fun<-function(x,NameChoice){
  return(x[which(x$name==NameChoice),])
}

fun(df,'ghi')

result:
ghi    3    7   11   15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (noting that the help page for `subset` specifically advises NOT to use it in a function);

```
func.in <- function(){cat("Enter colname and press enter:")
   readLines(n = 1)}  # No need for quotes since readline will "see" as character.

f <- function(inp)  # enter the dataframe of interest
        return(  inp[ , func.in()])

}

#Example of use:
> f(inp)
Enter colname and press enter:
X
[1] 25 67
```

Need to use the '[' function for extraction rather than `subset`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you will expecting this:

```
df
name val1 val2 val3 val4
abc    1    5    9   13
def    2    6   10   14
ghi    3    7   11   15
klm    4    8   12   16


f<- function(x,NameChoice) { 
  return( subset( x, name == NameChoice ) )
}

f(df,'abc')

result:
name val1 val2 val3 val4
abc    1    5    9   13
```